# The transformation relating two quintic polynomials

Tags: polynomials, transformation, quintics

I apologise if this a silly question. Is there a transformation relating the following two graphs:

1. $x^5 + -3 \sqrt{\frac{e}{5}}x^3 + ex + f$
2. $x^5 + ex + f$

if so is there any way to derive it like some sort of specialised tschirnhaus transformation.
Help would be appreciated.